# Rxjs catchError casuses TypeScript type error

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have an example from Angular. There are two interfaces. One defines `status` as string. The second one defines `status` values. The problem is the later one because the `catchError` function does not return proper type for it:

```js
export interface ThisInterfaceIsOk {
    status: string;
}


export interface ThisInterfaceCausesProblem {
    status: "OK" | "PROBLEM";
}


@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RegisterService {

    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
    }


    public registerValid(): Observable<ThisInterfaceIsOk> {
        return this.httpClient.get('http://example.com/api').pipe(
            map(response => response as ThisInterfaceIsOk),
            catchError(() => of({status: "WHATEVER"}))
        );
    }

    public registerInvalid(): Observable<ThisInterfaceCausesProblem> {
        return this.httpClient.get('http://example.com/api').pipe(
            map(respone => respone as ThisInterfaceCausesProblem),
            catchError(() => of({status: "OK"}))
        );
    }
}
```

The error is like `TS2322 Type Observable<ThisInterfaceCausesProblem|{status: string}> is not assignable to type Observable<ThisInterfaceCausesProblem>` but I really do not understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the line `catchError(() => of({status: "OK"}))` gives a return type of `{ status: string }`. Try replacing it with this: `catchError(() => of({status: "OK" as const}))`

Comment: I didn't know that syntax but It works. And it seems to be a much better solution than casting whole object to the interface (like `{status: "OK} as ThisInterfaceCausesProblem`). I'll accept your answer but need to wait like 3 mins:)

Comment: Anyway... that is strange because when I want to spy on the service in tests then I don't have to indicate that the string is a const. Meaning this works: `spyOn(service, 'registerInvalid').and.returnValue(of({status: "OK"}))`. Could you explain why?

Comment: `const foo = 'bar'` will mean `foo` has type `string`. `const foo = 'bar' as const` will mean `foo` has type `'bar'`. The javascript code it compiles to is the same in either case, it is just about the types. In the case of tests, the type of spys doesn't matter.